# sqlite3 выдает значение, как список. Но python думает что он ничего не выдал и выдает ошибку. Как это исправить?

Tags: python, sqlite, discord, sqlite3, discord.py

Код команды discord.py:

```
@commands.command()
    async def welcome(self, ctx, arg: str = None, arg2: int = None, *, arg3: str = None):
        try:
            for value in cursor.execute(f"SELECT owner_id FROM servers WHERE id={ctx.guild.id}"):#получаю id овнера сервера из таблицы sqlite3
                owner_id = value#записываю id в переменную
            owner_id = re.sub("[(|)|,|']", "", str(owner_id))#убираю лишние символы, т.к. slite3 выдает список
            owner_id = int(owner_id)
            if ctx.author.id == owner_id:#сравниваю id автора с id в переменной
              #дальше идет мой код
```

Но выдает ошибку:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'owner_id' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: 1. у вас нет сервера с переданным id 2. не используйте манипуляции со строками, делайте параметризированный запрос `cursor.execute("SELECT owner_id FROM servers WHERE id=?", (ctx.guild.id,))`

Answer (score 3):

У вас переменная создается в цикле, но если не будет итераций цикла, то она не будет создана, из-за чего и возникает та ошибка при попытке использовать переменную

Я бы убрал цикл, т.к. не может быть у вас несколько объектов с одним id, используя `fetchone`. А значения в запрос лучше привыкнуть передавать через параметры `?`

Пример:

```
value = cursor.execute("SELECT owner_id FROM servers WHERE id=?", [ctx.guild.id]).fetch_one()
owner_id = value[0] if value else None
if ctx.author.id == owner_id:#сравниваю id автора с id в переменной
    # дальше идет мой код
```

Но, в `value` будет `None`, если в таблице не будет сервера с указанным id, поэтому лучше предусмотреть вариант и проверять (поэтому добавил проверку `value[0] if value else None`)

Comment: Чем лучше передача значений через ‘?’

Comment: Значения будут сконвертированы из питоничьих типов в тип базы данных, плюс защита от инъекции sql-кода: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0